# Failed to resolve module specifier error - After an upgrade to angular 17

Tags: angular, typescript, esbuild, es2022, angular17

I'm upgrading my Angular project from angular V16 to V17, by following the official Angular guide https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=16.0-17.0

After performing the upgrade and running the project in the browser following the build using `ng build`, I encountered the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "project-name/chunk-BKTGOTTT.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

The project was building and running successfully with Angular version 16 without errors.

I suspect there might be an issue related to a configuration property that needs adjustment.

It's important to note that as a part of the upgrade, I switched the builder from `browser` to `browser-esbuild`.